# How to do migration using evolve in asp .net core with nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nhibernate, migration, code-first, evolve

I have to create a table in PSql database using code first approach in asp .net core with nHibernate ORM.  I have tried evolve migration.  I didn't get any error but table is not created in the database.  I don't know what's wrong in that.  Here is my code that I have used in **Program.cs**.  Please let me know how to do migration.

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {

        var target = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 string env = webBuilder.GetSetting("ENVIRONMENT");
                 env = string.IsNullOrEmpty(env) ? "Production" : env;

                 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
                 .AddEnvironmentVariables();

                 var configuration = builder.Build();

                 var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>(ConfigKeyNames.ConnectionString);
                 var connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
                 var evolve = new Evolve.Evolve(connection, msg => Log.Information(msg))
                 {
                     EmbeddedResourceAssemblies = new[] { typeof(SampleUserModel).Assembly },
                     IsEraseDisabled = (env == "Production"),
                     MustEraseOnValidationError = (env == "Production")
                 };

                 evolve.Migrate();

                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });

        return target;
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mistake in create script column names so that the table is not created in database.

```
"id" bigint NOT NULL
```

Column names in PSQL create script do not enclosed in **double quotes**. Here is my correct PSQL create table script for migration.

```
 CREATE TABLE public.sampleuser
 (
 id bigint NOT NULL ,
 userid bigint,
 name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
 address character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
 phonenumber bigint,
 isactive boolean,
 CONSTRAINT SampleUser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

CREATE SEQUENCE public.sampleuser_seq
 INCREMENT 1
 START 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 100;
```